# .htaccess to redirect URL with specific query-string, to a different domain, maintaining the query-string

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

### What I wish to do

I have one particular URL I need to redirect using `.htaccess`, based on a specific value being present in the query-string. A 301 permanent redirect header being sent to browser (that bit I know how to do).

#### The one URL to redirect is:

`https://www.mydomain.com.au/search-result/?location=western-australia`.

#### Where to redirect to

I want to redirect to a different domain: `https://wa.mydomain.com.au/search-result/?location=western-australia`.

#### Additional considerations

Note that there are other `.../search-result/` URLs that have different variables in the query strings, such as `?weather=...` or `?water=...`. For example, `https://www.mydomain.com.au/search-result/?location=western-australia&weather=part-shade&water=&pasture=`. If any of those variables are in the query string, this doesn't impact whether or not it gets redirected. **If `location=western-australia` is in the query-string, it should be redirected, along with its full query-string**.

There are also other location values that may occur in the string (other than `western-australia`. **These should not be redirected.**

As seen in the above example, it's possible multiple variables will be in the query string, such as `?location=western-australia&weather=&water=moderate&pasture=`.

So I need to test for the presence of  `location=western-australia` irrespective of whether or not it has other variables after it. Note that the `location=` variable is always the first in the overall query string.

I think it will be as simple as testing for the presence of `/search-result/` AND that it is followed by `?location=western-australia` in the query-string. Or just testing for `location=western-australia`.

#### What I came up with so far

I tried shown below. Note: I tried two version of the `RewriteCond` and two versions of the `RewriteRule`. I've left both versions, but commented them out):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/search-result/?$

# RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)location=western-australia($|&)

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(location=western-australia)

RewriteRule ^$ https://wa.mydomain.com.au/search-result/?%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,NC,L]

# RewriteRule ^$ https://wa.mydomain.com.au/search-result/?%1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

But it seems to have no effect.

Thank you.

Comment: Also see " Redirect URLs with query string using htaccess" : https://helponnet.com/2019/06/21/how-to-redirect-a-url-with-query-string-apache-htaccess/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you wish to redirect your URLs from subdomain `www.example.com` containing an exact query string to a new subdomain `wa.example.com` with the same query.

This htaccess will do the job:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)location=western-australia
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://wa.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks. I only want to redirect when the query string contains the variable and value I've mentioned in my question.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my Answer because I didn't understand well the first time

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Would you mind taking a moment to explain why your RewriteRule worked, and why mine didn't? Am I correct in thinking `^(.*)$` refers to the entire original URI, which is then replaced by `https://wa.example.com%{REQUEST_URI}`?

Comment: yes it s a wildcard for anything corresponding to the RewriteCond to be rewritten